# If Argument Defining Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

It appears as though the argument of my if statement is re-setting the value of the variable I am checking.

I have the following button

```
<select class="demobutton" id="currencytype" style="padding-left:2.3em;">
<option value="BTC">BTC</option><option value="XMR">XMR</option><option value="LTC">LTC</option><option value="ZEC">ZEC</option><option value="ETH">ETH</option></select>
```

and use the script

```
function changeData() {
                    var currency = document.getElementById("currencytype").value;
                    var daterange = document.getElementById("rangecalendar").value;
                    var imp = document.getElementById("impetus").value;
```

To extract the input of the button.

Then I analyze that input and modify data presented on the website accordingly.

```
if (currency = 'btc') {
                        alert(currency);
                        if (daterange = '08/21/17 - 12/03/17') {
                            if (imp = '1H') {
                                document.getElementById('roioutput').innerHTML = '542%';
                                document.getElementById('sharpe').innerHTML = '.403';
                                document.getElementById('alpha').innerHTML = '-.193';
                                document.getElementById('beta').innerHTML = '0.00';
                                $('#graph img').attr('src','images/graph1hbtc.png');
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

For debugging purposes, I included an alert in the code. When I use the alert to print the value of the variable currency before the if statement in my script, the value is the value in the input button which is what I want. However, the alert in the if statement shows me the value of whatever I am checking the variable against in the argument (in this case 'btc'). It is as though instead of checking if currency = 'btc', the if statement is setting currency = 'btc'.

Why is this and what can be done to prevent it?

If it helps to see my complete code in action, go [here](http://everestcapital.io/k2/index.html#demo)

Comment: You write `currency = 'btc'` then that's what you have. You want instead `currency === 'btc'`

Comment: `currency == 'btc'`

Comment: the `currency = 'btc'` is not the only time you used `=` to compare two values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It appears as though the argument of my if statement is re-setting the value of the variable I am checking.

You are completely right, it does.

```
if (currency = 'btc') {}
```

Changes the value of `currency` and returns `true` if there aren't any errors (e.g. `currency` is a constant).

You should use `==` or `===` to compare two values.

This should work for you:

```
if (currency === 'btc') {
                        alert(currency);
                        if (daterange === '08/21/17 - 12/03/17') {
                            if (imp === '1H') {
                                document.getElementById('roioutput').innerHTML = '542%';
                                document.getElementById('sharpe').innerHTML = '.403';
                                document.getElementById('alpha').innerHTML = '-.193';
                                document.getElementById('beta').innerHTML = '0.00';
                                $('#graph img').attr('src','images/graph1hbtc.png');
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

More info on that can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: I noticed you still had single = after daterange and imp arguments later on in the code. Should those be switched as well?

Comment: It actually does not appear that is working though it may be part of the solution. Now the if statement does not execute even when currency is 'btc'. I put an alert before the if statement and within the if statement. The alert before the if statement returns "btc" as the value of currency but the if statement does not execute as I do not see a second alert.